# Get last 3 words from the string?

Tags: php

How do you get last 3 words from the string?

I managed to get working doing like this:

```
$statusMessage = explode(" ", str_replace('&nbsp;'," ",$retStatus->plaintext));
$SliceDate = array_slice($statusMessage, -3, 3);
$date = implode(" ", $SliceDate);
echo $date;
```

Is there a shorter way? Maybe there is a PHP function that I did not know..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

explode() is good, but once you've done that you can use

```
$size = sizeof($statusMessage);
```

and last 3 are

```
$statusmessage[$size-1]; 
$statusmessage[$size-2]; 
$statusmessage[$size-3];
```

Comment: You mean count() instead of sizeof() ?

Comment: @user Both work. `count()` is easier to read and not confusing with C's `sizeof` operator.

Comment: Indeed you do, on StackOverflow!  +1 for the count idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('#(?:\s\w+){3}$#', $statusMessage );
```

Comment: If my string length less then 3. then its return empty.

Answer (score 0):

preg_match("/(?:\w+\s*){1,3}$/", $input_line, $output_array);

this catches 1 to 3 words and if the row is only 3 long, other regex one was close

Comment: Its working fine if we have only the alphanumeric value. But when I added dot(.), smicolon(;) and any other special character then the calculation is getting wrong.